Roles are not working in my springboot app
I am trying to implement Roles and Permissions(Authorities) using spring security. I am using JWT for managing sessions. This is my Enum class that i have created for my roles
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public enum Role {
    USER(Collections.emptySet()),
    ADMIN(Set.of(ADMIN_READ,
            ADMIN_CREATE,
            ADMIN_DELETE,
            ADMIN_UPDATE,
            MANAGER_CREATE,
            MANAGER_DELETE,
            MANAGER_UPDATE,
            MANAGER_READ)),

    MANAGER(Set.of(
            MANAGER_CREATE,
            MANAGER_DELETE,
            MANAGER_UPDATE,
            MANAGER_READ));

    @Getter
    private final Set<Permissions> permissions;

    public List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(){
        //converting the permissions of the roles into a list of authorities
        var authorities = getPermissions()
                .stream()
                .map(permissions ->new SimpleGrantedAuthority(permissions.name()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        //adding the role also as part of the authorities so this will contain the role and the permissions inside the authority list
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + this.name()));
        return authorities;
    }
}

This is my permissions class
@Getter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public enum Permissions {

    ADMIN_READ("admin::read"),

    ADMIN_UPDATE("admin::update"),

    ADMIN_CREATE("admin::create"),

    ADMIN_DELETE("admin::delete"),

    MANAGER_READ("management::read"),

    MANAGER_UPDATE("management::update"),

    MANAGER_CREATE("management::create"),

    MANAGER_DELETE("management::delete");

    private final String permissions;
}

This is a snippet from the security config class
 .requestMatchers(ADMIN_URL).hasRole(ADMIN.name())
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,ADMIN_URL).hasAuthority("ROLE_"+ADMIN_READ.name())
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,ADMIN_URL).hasAuthority(ADMIN_CREATE.name())
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT,ADMIN_URL).hasAuthority(ADMIN_UPDATE.name())
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE,ADMIN_URL).hasAuthority(ADMIN_DELETE.name())

I have user created that has admin privilege but when i call my endpoint (ADMIN_URL) I get a 403 response (using postman for test)
I have tried adding roles_ to the authorities but I am still getting the same error

you are aware that using JWTs as session is dangerous, and not recommended.

Please clarify what you meant by dangerous? I am new to learning spring security

If you are learning spring security i recommend that you learn from the official docs than reading blogposts that build homemade security solutions. There are plenty of resources if you google, explaining why you should not use JWTs as sessions.

I just discovered that the getAuthorities() method will be called when the hasRole("ADMIN") is to be invoked to check the roles of a user. Therefore my getAuthortites() needed to return the list of authorities available for the user.
I changed the getAuthorties() method in my Users class to this and it worked.
 @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return role.getAuthorities();
    }

